# Why much more gas are used when calling a function for the first time?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Here is my code.

```
contract Demo {
    function add1(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) { 
        if (a==0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

```
contract Test {
    Demo demo = new Demo();

    function testGas() public {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        demo.add1(1, 2);
        uint256 endGas = gasleft();
        uint256 gasUsage1 = startGas - endGas;

        startGas = gasleft();
        demo.add1(1, 2);
        endGas = gasleft();
        uint256 gasUsage2 = startGas - endGas;
    }
}
```

The gasUsage1 is 6434 and gasUsage2 is 1919.
When the function is called a third time, the gas usage is the same as the second time.
I tested other functions and the results were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main contributions: reading the address from storage, and then touching it.

1. By doing `demo.add1(1, 2);` the code first needs to read (SLOAD) the address of `demo` saved in storage. The gas cost is 2100 the first time (cold access), then 100 (warm access). [docs](https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#a6-sload)
2. Calling the demo contract will "touch" its address. The gas cost the first time (cold access) is 2600, then its 100. [docs](https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#a5-balance-extcodesize-extcodehash)

This explain a 2000+2500 = 4500 difference.

So, 6434-(1919+4500) = 15. There's only 15 extra gas, that's probably due to stack/memory operations.